# Need to display a text list of records not on my list

Tags: python, arcgis

I need to search a feature class for multiple text entries and display all the values and their object ids that aren't on the list, i.e. find all the mistakes. (Basically, want to search for text entries such as AVE, TRL, ST, and display entries that aren't formatted like that).  I want to write it in python.

Can I use the searchCursor to do this, or is it something more complicated.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!  I think this is the solution, but it is still printing AVE.  Any idea as to why?

```
import arcpy

fc = "Z:\Street_Centerlines"
field = "StSuffix"
field1 = "OBJECTID"

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:

    if field == "AVE":
        pass

    else:
        print(row.getValue(field1)); print(row.getValue(field))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` variable is equal to "StSuffix", so `field == "AVE"` is always false. I think you want this:

```
valid_values = 'AVE', 'TRL', 'ST'
for row in cursor:
    value = row.getValue(field)
    if value in valid_values:
        continue

    print("Invalid value: OBJECTID={}, StSuffix={}".format(
        row.getValue(field1), 
        value
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still outputs every value, not the 'invalid' ones

Comment: @user2733678: sorry, there was an obvious bug: `if field in valid_values`should be `if value in valid_values:`. Fixed.